# How do we test shuffle function effectively?

Tags: automated-testing

I am working on reviewing legacy test cases at the moment.

There is a shuffle feature,

- Items are given in a default order
- Items are shuffled in a different order every time they are loaded into a web browser; it is possible for items to be given in the default order too.

Currently, I am testing this shuffle feature by

- Remember the default order, default_order
- Load the items for the first time, remember the order, first_shuffled_order
- Load the items for the second time, remember the order, second_shuffled_order
- Compare default_order, first_shuffled_order and second_shuffled_order, each item should be present and at least one item order should be different.

But there is a chance for this test case to trigger a false failure, e.g. the default order is triggered twice in a row, then the test will fail.

Is there a better way to do this?

- We can introduce more shuffling but it is still possible for this testing logic to trigger a false failure.

Comment: You cannot test randomness deterministically.

Comment: I would also ask if probability of defult order is the same as other orders? If yes, then this is about testing random number generation (where a random number determines random order).

Comment: Shuffles the items n times where n is the number of items. Then assert that each item's position has a uniform distribution over all the shuffles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can test is shuffle N times(use loop) in a test and it should be at least x% times different in total.

For example, if I shuffle 100 times at least 70-80 times(or whatever acceptable percentage) %, it should be different.

I cannot expect a dice to come up with different number 7th time in any case :)

Comment: How do you define *x*, i.e. acceptable percentage?

Comment: That is something , OP has to decide.

Comment: I found the suggestion in ["Testing a Random Number Generator"](https://www.johndcook.com//Beautiful_Testing_ch10.pdf): *"We do not have to look too closely at how often tests pass. Correct generators usually pass tests, and buggy generators usually fail."*

Comment: Nice read @dzieciou.